# Proper way to perform camera preview mirroring mode

Tags: c#, windows-8, microsoft-metro

Currently, when tested using [Media capture using capture device sample](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsapps/Media-Capture-Sample-adf87622), I realize the camera is not something I want. **I wish it to be in mirroring mode. Currently, it is not.**

1. For a camera preview to be in mirroring mode, may I know is it hardware dependent or hardware independent. Possible that if I run the same code with different hardware, the camera preview will be in mirroring mode? If it is hardware dependent, how can I check whether my camera preview is in mirroring/non-mirroring mode?
2. To make it in mirroring mode, I try to follow [this thread](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/winappswithcsharp/thread/51d3d2c2-0407-4c6d-9691-942939344aac). I try `MediaCapture.SetPreviewMirroring(true)`. No effect as all. The camera preview is still in non-mirroring mode.
3. I try `captureElement.RenderTransform = new ScaleTransform() { ScaleX = -1 };`. The whole camera preview become plain grey color.
4. The last approach I would like to try, is try to perform flipping in C++ code through `MediaCapture.AddEffectAsync()`. However, that need to go back to my **first question**. Can I just simply perform flipping, or do I first need to check whether the incoming buffer is in mirroring/non-mirroring mode? If yes, how do I check?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use

```
    <CaptureElement x:Name="previewElement" Margin="0" Stretch="UniformToFill" RenderTransformOrigin="0.5,0.5">
        <CaptureElement.RenderTransform>
            <CompositeTransform ScaleX="-1"/>
        </CaptureElement.RenderTransform>
    </CaptureElement>
```

The key lied on `RenderTransformOrigin="0.5,0.5"`. We need to flip from center of preview.

Comment: This doesn't work. A capture element is not a regular element that you can just flip or rotate, the camera dumps frames into it and ignores orientation or transformations.

Answer (score 2):

For those looking for a more updated answer since this question was asked, the proper way on UWP and WinUI is to set the `FlowDirection="RightToLeft"` on the `CaptureElement`.

```
<CaptureElement x:Name="previewElement" FlowDirection="RightToLeft"/>
```